# Installing Tensorflow GPU - Cannot find libcublas.so.9.0 even though its present and in path

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow

I run into the error

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even though the file exists and the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are set. I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0

The file exists:
[image: File exists]

And the path contains this folder:

[image: LD_LIBRARY_PATH]

The stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: there is a colon at the beginning of your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, remove it, as it might affect.

Comment: it turned out to be a driver issue. I went back to Ubuntu 16.04 and did a fresh install of the Nvidia drivers and I was able to install Tensorflow_gpu without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a driver issue. I went back to Ubuntu 16.04,  did a fresh install of Ubuntu and the Nvidia drivers and I was able to install Tensorflow_gpu without a problem.